# Subqueries in Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM collection_companies cc 
LEFT JOIN collection_company_links ccl ON cc.id = ccl.collection_company_id 
    AND ccl.id  = 
        (
           SELECT MAX(id) 
           FROM collection_company_links ccl2  
           WHERE ccl2.collection_company_id = ccl.collection_company_id
        )
```

```
$data = DB::table('collection_companies as cc')
      ->leftJoin('collection_company_links as ccl', 'cc.id', '=', 'ccl.collection_company_id')
      ->where('ccl.id', function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw("MAX(id)"))->from('collection_company_links as ccl2')
        ->where('ccl2.collection_company_id', 'ccl.collection_company_id');
      });
```

I want to do the query with the Laravel query builder. I have tried the above code but it doesn't work because 'ccl.collection_company_id' is passed as a value. How should I do the query?

Comment: `->whereColumn()` instead of `->where()`

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't used that method before.